# Laravel Blade compileString gives me a Blank Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried to create a new blade directive in my AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php
public function boot()
{
  Blade::directive('test', function () {
    return Blade::compileString('@if(1==1) test @endif');
  });
}
```

And then call this directive in my view:

`@test()`

But it's not work and gives me a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try several things but finally i fix this by copy and paste blade directive code from BladeCompiler.php to my custom directive instead of using compileString

Answer (score 0):

You get a blank page because `Blade::compileString` is a facade to a stateful singleton object. That object doesn't expect you to call it.

As a workaround you could create a new instance of the compiler and go with it:

```
Blade::directive('endtabs', function ($exp) {
    $content1 = sprintf("@include('%s', ['tabs' => \$tabs])", 'backend/tabs/test');
    $compiler = new BladeCompiler(app('files'), app('config')['view.compiled']);
    return $compiler->compileString($content1);
});
```